# How can i have space on the right side of the form

Tags: html, css

```css
.contact .container .message {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 30px;
  min-width: 60%;
}

.message form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.message form input,
.message form textarea {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 15px;
  resize: none;
}

.message form textarea {
  min-height: 200px;
}

.message form input::placeholder,
.message form textarea::placeholder {
  color: #000;
}

.message form input[type="submit"] {
  max-width: 100px;
  background: #2196f3;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="contact">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="heading">
      <h2>Contact Me</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="left">
      <div class="detail">
        <div class="icon">
          <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="text">
          <h3>Address
            <h3>
              <p>xxx street<br></p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="detail">
        <div class="icon">
          <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="text">
          <h3>No Handphone
            <h3>
              <p>012345678</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="detail">
        <div class="icon">
          <i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="text">
          <h3>Email
            <h3>
              <p>blabla@gmail.com</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="message">
      <form>
        <h3>Message Me</h3>
        <input type="text" name="" placeholder="Full Name">
        <input type="email" name="" placeholder="Email">
        <textarea placeholder="Your Message"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="send">
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm a beginner using css and i am try to build mini project so this is the project, I don't know why the form I have is full width to the right, even though I'm using padding on all sides. I want to make the form display have a space on the right side. I've used padding for all sides but it still doesn't work, I don't know what to do to solve this problem. Can someone help me.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to is to add margin to the wrapper of form instead. eg. `.message` class

```css
.contact .container .message {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 30px;
  min-width: 60%;
  margin-right: 20%; 
}

.message form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.message form input,
.message form textarea {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 15px;
  resize: none;
}

.message form textarea {
  min-height: 200px;
}

.message form input::placeholder,
.message form textarea::placeholder {
  color: #000;
}

.message form input[type="submit"] {
  max-width: 100px;
  background: #2196f3;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="contact">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="heading">
      <h2>Contact Me</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="left">
      <div class="detail">
        <div class="icon">
          <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="text">
          <h3>Address
            <h3>
              <p>xxx street<br></p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="detail">
        <div class="icon">
          <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="text">
          <h3>No Handphone
            <h3>
              <p>012345678</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="detail">
        <div class="icon">
          <i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="text">
          <h3>Email
            <h3>
              <p>blabla@gmail.com</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="message message-overwrite">
      <form>
        <h3>Message Me</h3>
        <input type="text" name="" placeholder="Full Name">
        <input type="email" name="" placeholder="Email">
        <textarea placeholder="Your Message"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="send">
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```